# Android: Is 2D drawing faster than setting images in ImageViews?

Tags: android, drawing

I am creating a dress up game, and this involves putting lots of images on top of each other. The application by itself can work fast with no lags, but if a slide animation is added to the item to be dressed when the character is fully dressed (10 images or more on top of each other), a bad lag happens. I believe this happens because the OS invalidates all the ImageViews and draws them all again. The images are of png type and they mostly are around 10 kilobytes.

Would using graphics and drawing on the layout make it faster? Or would it be the same thing as setting images from resources?

I can't actually try it right now because it involves a major re-writing of the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement the app using OpenGL, it should be more faster than now. Before doing that, you might want to double check that you have all the image resources scaled correctly for the target devices (mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, and xxhdpi). Scaling up drawables in runtime can cause a significant performance penalty on some devices, especially for animations.

Comment: Yes the scaling is correct, I am sure of that. I have been reading about OpenGL and it seems to be very complicated for this simple job that I am doing. Aren't there any other options?